# Highcharts:Heatmap not show rectangle when single data-point

Tags: charts, highcharts, heatmap, highmaps

I am plotting heatmap using highcharts. When there are many data data-points it works properly but when there is signle point like this :[[1.4409601E12,0,92]] it fails to show the rectangle of heatmap. However on hovering it show the value in tooltip but doesn't render heatmap. What I observed in console of developer tool of chrome it shows that there was a  plotted but its X cordinate was  -2073599976 , When I made it 0 on browser's inspect element console it started appearing but on code side I am unable to locate where to make the change.
when there are 2 or more points its x sets 25 or 26 and plots well.

Any Solution will be great help.

Comment: Please use fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/dtwa6bm6/ to see the code

Comment: For me this works properly, see example (http://jsfiddle.net/dtwa6bm6/1/) value with E is last elements in second row.

Comment: Hi @SebastianBochan Thanks for reply, I have edited your fiddle to re-produce the issue I am having. Now the map data is having only one point and its not showing heatmap's rectangle for that single point.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B13Q_6knq4vCbkhhNGI0WVhVaWc/view?usp=sharing   Please look at the screen-shot I have taken from your fiddle...I have highlighted the point . It has been drawn but due to its X -cordinate showing value in  x="-10713599876" its not showing that rectangular <rect> point.

Comment: <g class="highcharts-series highcharts-tracker" visibility="visible" zIndex="0.1" transform="translate(338,301) rotate(90) scale(-1,1) scale(1 1)" style="" width="274" height="248" clip-path="url(#highcharts-2)"><rect x="-10713599876" y="263" width="21427200000" height="11" stroke="#7cb5ec" stroke-width="1" fill="rgb(31,171,90)"></rect></g>

Comment: @SebastianBochan any suggestion on this,expecting your reply.

Comment: Im waiting for feedback from developer, who codes that. If I will know something, I let you know.

Comment: This issue is resolved in Highcharts, see https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4530. Demo with the fix applied: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/dtwa6bm6/7/

Comment: Thanks A lot @TorsteinHønsi .Seen the fiddle ,working fine.                                    for now I will  replace my  heatmap.js with your updated heatmap.js at http:// github.highcharts.com/90ffe87767e/modules/heatmap.js                              Thanks again  SebastianBochan and  TorsteinHønsi